# Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156?

Tags: flutter, gradle, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 32s
  Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Can you post the specific error occuring and your code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: He is trying to run a build of flutter apk on emulator and physical device, hence the error on the console/terminal.. Kindly assist if you can Thanks

Comment: try running `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`. If it didn't work then try updating your packages `flutter pub outdate`

Comment: In my case, i started facing this issue when my flutter plugin got updated, so had to update my project to support latest flutter sdk version.